# UIWebView disable location prompt

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to disable the location prompt (or auto decline/accept it) that pops up when you visit certain websites that ask for locations? I am not using a MKMapView because my app will be not be just viewing maps (it just may visit websites that might have maps on it).

I'm guessing since the prompt is not being controlled by my app, but by the iOS system, I probably will not be able to auto decline/accept the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do that. Not with **UIWebView**, not with any iOS browser.

Comment: So, it isn't possible to just disable the prompt?  Is the only way through the settings? (Which is obviously off limits within the app to change it)

Comment: No you cannot disable it. It is there for the safety of the user.

Comment: You can intercept any web based calls via JS or the web view's callback for loading links. What Pablo says is an un creative defaulted answer. The only limit, is how accurate you want everything to be an how much work you want to put into it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as disabling the prompt from within an IOS app while loading a UIWebView, it **is** possible.

You will need to intercept the html before it gets loaded into the UIWebView then find which part of it triggers the GPS/Location Prompt. Once you found it, you simply remove it from the html then feed the html into the UIWebView thus 'disabling' the prompt. However, as a result, the webpage will be missing that element.

Answer (score 0):

I know no way to prevent the prompt, I hope it will be implemented as a property of the UIWebView.

The dialog is not there for the safety of the user, when it comes to UIWebViews. The app containing the view has already asked for locations access, and it can be enabled and disabled on settings. To ask for location access both from the app and from the web view, I would regard as a bug.